# List item container like whatsapp

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-linearlayout

I'm trying to get this effect on a list item in a list

https://ssl.gstatic.com/android/market/com.whatsapp/ss-2-320-480-160-0-a637ec45d9d24eb0f50c610657654007223dbe19

What do I have to do - override a LayoutContainer and implement my own onDraw method?

I'm not very good when it comes to graphics/drawing (in code) so can someone give me some starting ideas on how to implement this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general it would be much easier.  define a 9-patch that can expand that is the background "bubble" and will serve as the background tot he listviewitem.  you could dynamically add views (images, textviews, etc) depending on content, or if your needs are simpler, you could just have a single listviewItem.